# cannot figure beautifulsoup string sum

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hello I want to **scrape** a webpage. I posted my code but the line which I targeted is important. It doesn't worked. I mean there is no error but also no output. My code is there. I need to sum to strings and there is the problem.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url='http://www.sis.itu.edu.tr/tr/ders_programlari/LSprogramlar/prg.php'
html_content = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")

url_course_main='http://www.sis.itu.edu.tr/tr/ders_programlari/LSprogramlar/prg.php?fb='


url_course=url_course_main+soup.find_all('option')[1].get_text()    <---this line
html_content_course=requests.get(a).text
soup_course=BeautifulSoup(html_content_course,'lxml')
for j in soup_course.find_all('td'):
    print(j.get_text())
```

When I am changing the line which I showed to

```
url_course=url_course_main+'AKM'
```

it worked.

Also `soup.find_all('option')[1].get_text()` is equal to AKM.
Can you guess where the mistake is.

Comment: So what is the value of `a` you're passing here `html_content_course=requests.get(a).text`

Comment: The line of code you highlighted it working just fine

Comment: a is 'http://www.sis.itu.edu.tr/tr/ders_programlari/LSprogramlar/prg.php?fb=AKM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `requests` module, try Python's standard `urllib.request`. It seems that `requests` module has problem opening the page:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url='http://www.sis.itu.edu.tr/tr/ders_programlari/LSprogramlar/prg.php'
html_content = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
url_course_main='http://www.sis.itu.edu.tr/tr/ders_programlari/LSprogramlar/prg.php?fb='
url_course=url_course_main+soup.find_all('option')[1].get_text()
html_content_course=urllib.request.urlopen(url_course).read()
soup_course=BeautifulSoup(html_content_course,'lxml')

for j in soup_course.find_all('td'):
    print(j.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
2019-2020 Yaz Dönemi AKM Kodlu Derslerin Ders Programı 

...
```

Comment: BTW: problem is that `get_text()` gives `'AKM '` with space at the end and `requests` sends url with this space - and server can't find file `'AKM '` with space.

Comment: @furas Nice catch. I tried changing headers first and then switched to `urllib`. Interesting that `urllib` strips this space.

Comment: I started also with all headers from `DevTool` and later with `Session()` and I found this accidently :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that `get_text()` gives `'AKM '` with space at the end and `requests` sends url with this space - and server can't find file `'AKM '` with space.

I used `><` in string `'>{}<'.format(param)` to show this space - `>AKM <` - because without `><` it seems OK.

Code needs `get_text(strip=True)` or `get_text().strip()` to remove this space.

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.sis.itu.edu.tr/tr/ders_programlari/LSprogramlar/prg.php'
html_content = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'lxml')

url_course_main = 'http://www.sis.itu.edu.tr/tr/ders_programlari/LSprogramlar/prg.php?fb='

param = soup.find_all('option')[1].get_text() 
print('>{}<'.format(param))   # I use `> <` to show spaces

param = soup.find_all('option')[1].get_text(strip=True)
print('>{}<'.format(param))   # I use `> <` to show spaces

url_course = url_course_main + param

html_content_course = requests.get(url_course).text

soup_course = BeautifulSoup(html_content_course, 'lxml')
for j in soup_course.find_all('td'):
    print(j.get_text())
```